# Keeping columns' attributes in a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

When subsetting some values in a column of a `data.table` object, the attributes of the column are preserved as one can see in the following example.

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1L)
dt1 <- data.table(a=runif(5L))
setattr(dt1$a, "foo", "bar")
dt1[1:2, a:=runif(.N)]
dt1[1:2, a]
##  [1] 0.8983897 0.9446753
##  attr(,"foo")
##  [1] "bar"
```

However, if one redefine the whole column, attributes are lost.

```
dt1[, a:=runif(.N)]
dt1[1:2, a]
##  [1] 0.6607978 0.6291140
```

I guess this behaviour come from the fact that, when subsetting some values of a column, one only update those elements (by reference) while, when subsetting the whole column, one does not really update some elements of the column, but replace the whole column (still by reference).

I understand that this behaviour is nice when one wants to change the class of a column without having to drop it and reassign it (e.g. `dt1[, a:=as.integer(a)]` would work even if `dt[, a]` was previously of class `numeric`), but I'm wondering if there is a way to get around this and force the column to keep its original attributes (including its class, obviously) even when replacing all its values.

Thanks!

Comment: You can trick it into updating by row with `dt1[seq(nrow(dt1)), a := runif(.N)]`